# Unable to copy a table from a word document and paste it in to a excel sheet in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Following is the code snippet i tried

```
       r.Cells(3).Range.Copy()
       .Sheets("sheet4").Range("F" & k).Select()
      .Sheets("sheet4").Cells(k, 6).Columnwidth = 14
      .Sheets("sheet4").paste()
                k = k + 1
```

this doesnt copy the entire string inside one cell.I tried to use the pastespecial()

when i use pastespecial its showing error that pastespecial is not a member of Application Class

```
     .Sheets("sheet4").Range("F" & k).pasteSpecial(ExApp.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, False, False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried this before, but it seems to be an Excel-Word coordination issue. From my MS Office coupling experience, I know that there are many alternatives, which theoretically should be fine, provoking errors. Instead spending time on finding out a working alternative (perhaps there is none), why not removing the problem (Excel-Word communication)? You can store the Word value in a temporary variable and write this variable to the Excel cell.

Comment: Thanks I did , but a dot is coming at the end when i assign to a string variable. Can you help ?

Comment: A dot? This is not provoked by the suggested temporary storage for sure. Also the reading/writing from/to Excel and Word is very reliable (there are some communication/incompatibility problems but you always get an error message). Inspect the input cell (r.Cells(3)) and make sure that the destination one (.Sheets("sheet4").Range("F" & k)) is blank before writing anything. Other reason might be the destination cell formatting. But I cannot tell without seeing the exact data and the rest of the code.